# RODBC connection string for active directory username/password

Tags: active-directory, odbc, rodbc

I'd like to make RODBC connection using an **active directory** account

The following only works for **sql server** username and password

```
odbcDriverConnect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=abc; Database=abcd; Uid=uu; Pwd=pp')
```

When I put the active directory username and password in the above format, it doesn't work:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 18456, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'uu'.
```

What's the connection string for active directory?

I tried [These ones](https://www.connectionstrings.com/active-directory/). They don't work - seem to work like windows authentication:

```
odbcDriverConnect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=abc; Database=abcd; Provider=ADSDSOObject;User Id=uu; Password=pp')
# RODBC Connection 19
# Details:
#     case=nochange
# DRIVER=SQL Server
# SERVER=abc
# UID=
# Trusted_Connection=Yes
# APP=RStudio
# WSID=xxx
# DATABASE=abcd
```